# Pythonic way to convert XLS to CSV, where XLS contains PNG file in some coloumn

Tags: python, excel, csv

I do have an excel file with N ROWS and N columns. Few of the Columns contain PNG files inside that excel file. How do I convert this excel file to CSV without ignoring PNG file?

Can anyone suggest a good pythonic way / Some module or tools in order to achieve this?

Comment: "Without ignoring the PNG file"? So what do you want to do with the PNG images?

Comment: Can you already convert a XLS file without PNGs to CSV?

Comment: I have a script to convert Excel files to csv here: http://pastebin.com/LK9LrwPB. I haven't built in any handling for images, but feel free to use this as a starting point if you want to.

Comment: @Codemonkey I want to compare PNG files with previously stored PNGs. I have no idea how PNG will be stored (byte codes or in the form of some tags in xml) However, I have seen few MS-Word Documents if opened with winzip, we can retrieve as XML and if MS-Word has PNG files those will be converted into XML tags with some unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to write code, but you can use convertor and it's fast and good.

```
sudo apt-get install gnumeric
```

and you can do like this :

```
ssconvert yout file.xls output_name.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) to read the Excel file, then [base64](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) to encode the PNG images as ASCII symbols so you can include them in the CSV file.

*Note: I don't know for sure if you can read the binary data of embedded PNG images with openpyxl, so you might have to try different Python Excel libraries.*